Multiple wireguard interfaces with the same IP
Client IP: 10.1.1.100; Server IP: 10.1.1.101
Is it possible to have 1000 Wireguard interfaces on a client VM with

Same IP address attached to all interfaces
Different listening ports
Same Endpoint IP, with different listening port
Same Allowed IP subnet for all peers (10.1.1.0/23).

The server will have the same setup as client (same IP and different listening ports for all 1k interfaces), and there is a one-to-one communication mapping, for eg. client wg0 communicates with server wg0 and so on until client wg1000 communicates with server wg1000. Traffic will be sent across all interfaces concurrently.
I intend to create seperate network namespaces for each wireguard interface. Finally, the intension is to have 1000 seperate tunnels between client and server, using the same IP for all interfaces. Will this setup create 1000 seperate tunnels, or just 1 tunnel, as the IP is same for all interfaces?
This is how I intend to configure each interface:
# Set up ns0
sudo ip netns exec ns0 ip link set lo up
sudo ip netns exec ns0 ip link add dev wg0 type wireguard
sudo ip netns exec ns0 ip link set wg0 up
sudo ip netns exec ns0 ip address add 10.1.1.100/32 dev wg0
sudo ip netns exec ns0 wg set wg0 listen-port 51820
sudo ip netns exec ns0 wg set wg0 private-key /etc/wireguard/ns0_privatekey
sudo ip netns exec ns0 wg set wg0 peer $SERVER_NS0_PUBLIC_KEY endpoint 10.1.1.200:51820 allowed-ips 10.1.1.0/23
sudo ip netns exec ns0 ip route add 10.1.1.0/23 dev wg0


try with 2. What's the result?

From the form of your question it's evident that you don't fully understand how the network stack works, thus the solution you're asking for isn't needed at all.
